# 2022年現在、TCP輻輳制御アルゴリズムのシェア率はどのようになっているのでしょうか？

Tags: tcp

## 背景

[TCP技術入門](https://gihyo.jp/book/2019/978-4-297-10623-2)を読んで、TCPについて学んでいます。

## Reno/NewRenoとの親和性

TCP輻輳制御アルゴリズムを評価する指標の一つに、Reno/NewRenoとの親和性があることを理解しました。

> ただし，輻輳ウインドウサイズを大きく保とうとする傾向が強すぎて（＝アグレッシブ過ぎて⁠）⁠，Reno/NewRenoとの親和性が低いという課題がありました。つまり，HighSpeed TCPやScalable TCPが帯域を独占してしまうため，Reno/NewRenoと併用することができませんでした。インターネットでは不特定多数の人々／モノによる通信データが転送されるため，このようなアグレッシブ性の高すぎるアルゴリズムは適していません。

https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/tcp-cc/0003 引用

## 質問

2022年現在、TCP輻輳制御アルゴリズムのシェア率はどのようになっているのでしょうか？
もし、もしReno/NewRenoのシェア率が十分低い（低くなる）のであれば、今後はReno/NewRenoとの親和性ではなく、別の輻輳制御アルゴリズムとの親和性が重要になると思いました。

輻輳制御アルゴリズムの情報はTCPヘッダには存在しないので、輻輳制御アルゴリズムのシェア率は簡単には分からなさそうです。
しかし、OSによって輻輳制御アルゴリズムのデフォルト値は決まっている（はず？）なので、OSのシェア率からTCP輻輳制御アルゴリズムのシェア率が推測できるかと思い、質問しました。